# Is there a way to start parsing a file from a location onward of last parse in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

Here is my logstash configuration (modified from answer of [How to write grok pattern in logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756763/how-to-write-grok-pattern-in-logstash))

Here are issues/questions I have:

**Slowness:** My file is 50 MB in size and logstash is taking a long time    in parsing it. Is there some configuration which is causing this  slowness or is there some other reason or is logstash slow in parsing    file of this size.

**Start parsing logs from last parsed location** as I    will be sending these parsed events to ELK.

**Handle multiline when this is last line in logs.**

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/u/bansalp/activemq_primary_plugin.stats.log.0"
### For testing and continual process of the same file, remove these before produciton
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
### Lets read the logfile and recombine multi line details
    codec => multiline {
      # Grok pattern names are valid! :)
      pattern => "^\[%{YEAR}%{MONTHNUM}%{MONTHDAY}\s*%{TIME}"
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}
filter {
    ### Let's get some high level data before we split the line (note: anything you grab before the split gets copied)
    if [message] =~ "logPerDestinationStats" {
        grok {
            match => { 
                "message" => "^\[%{YEAR:yr}%{MONTHNUM:mnt}%{MONTHDAY:daynum}\s*%{TIME:time}\s*%{TZ:timezone}\s*(%{DATA:thread_name})\s*%{JAVACLASS:javaclass}#%{WORD:method}\s*%{LOGLEVEL}\]\s*%{DATA}:%{DATA:msg}"
            }
        }
        ### Split the lines back out to being a single line now. (this may be a \r or \n, test which one)
        split { 
            "field" => "message"
        }
        ### Ok, the lines should now be independent, lets add another grok here to get the patterns as dictated by your example [fieldA: str | field2: 0...] etc.
        ### Note: you should look to change the grok pattern to better suit your requirements, I used DATA here to quickly capture your content
        if [message] =~ "^\[destName" {
            grok {
                break_on_match => false
                match => { "message" => "^\[%{DATA}:\s*%{DATA:destName}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:enqueueCount}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:dequeueCount}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:dispatchCount}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:expiredCount}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:inflightCount}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:msgsHeld}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:msgsCached}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:memoryPercentUsage}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:memoryUsage}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:memoryLimit}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:avgEnqueueTimeMs}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:maxEnqueueTimeMs}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:minEnqueueTimeMs}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:currentConsumers}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:currentProducers}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:blockedSendsCount}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:blockedSendsTimeMs}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:minMsgSize}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:maxMsgSize}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:avgMsgSize}\s*\|\s*%{DATA}:\s*%{NUMBER:totalMsgSize}\]$" }
            }
        }
        mutate {
        convert => { "message" => "string" }
            add_field => {
                "session_timestamp" => "%{yr}-%{mnt}-%{daynum} %{time} %{timezone}"
                "load_timestamp" => "%{@timestamp}"
            }
            remove_field => ["yr","mnt", "daynum", "time", "timezone"]
        }
    }
}
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

**Same sample logs**

```
[20170513 06:08:29.734 EDT (StatsCollector-1) bansalp.tools.jms.ActiveMQLoggingPlugin$ActiveMQDestinationStatsCollector#logPerDestinationStats INFO] ActiveMQ Destination Stats (97 destinations):
[destName: topic://topic1 | enqueueCount: 1 | dequeueCount: 1 | dispatchCount: 1 | expiredCount: 0 | inflightCount: 0 | msgsHeld: 0 | msgsCached: 0 | memoryPercentUsage: 0 | memoryUsage: 0 | memoryLimit: 536870912 | avgEnqueueTimeMs: 0.0 | maxEnqueueTimeMs: 0 | minEnqueueTimeMs: 0 | currentConsumers: 1 | currentProducers: 0 | blockedSendsCount: 0 | blockedSendsTimeMs: 0 | minMsgSize: 2392 | maxMsgSize: 2392 | avgMsgSize: 2392.0 | totalMsgSize: 2392]
[destName: topic://topic2 | enqueueCount: 0 | dequeueCount: 0 | dispatchCount: 0 | expiredCount: 0 | inflightCount: 0 | msgsHeld: 0 | msgsCached: 0 | memoryPercentUsage: 0 | memoryUsage: 0 | memoryLimit: 536870912 | avgEnqueueTimeMs: 0.0 | maxEnqueueTimeMs: 0 | minEnqueueTimeMs: 0 | currentConsumers: 3 | currentProducers: 0 | blockedSendsCount: 0 | blockedSendsTimeMs: 0 | minMsgSize: 0 | maxMsgSize: 0 | avgMsgSize: 0.0 | totalMsgSize: 0]
```

Comment: How slow is your logstash? What are the number of cores the machine on which logstash is running?

Comment: It is a 8 core machine (though not completely free). What I observed was it is taking more than 1 hour in parsing this data. Do you feel there is some issue with configuration.

Comment: It says "Settings: Default pipeline workers: 20
Pipeline main started" and stays there for than 1 hour and I finally need to kill the process using cntrl-C

Comment: Who do you see in the logs of logstash? If you are using logstash >5, run this command to verify the stats of your logstash curl -XGET 'logstashIp:9600/_node/stats/pipeline?pretty'.

Comment: I found this in "{:timestamp=>"2017-05-06T03:02:34.974000-0400", :message=>"translation missing: en.logstash.runner.configuration.file-not-found", :level=>:error}
{:timestamp=>"2017-05-06T03:08:05.388000-0400", :message=>"translation missing: en.logstash.runner.configuration.file-not-found", :level=>:error}
{:timestamp=>"2017-05-06T05:12:35.208000-0400", :message=>"translation missing: en.logstash.runner.configuration.file-not-found", :level=>:error}" in logstash.log-20170508.

Comment: I have tested your config file and there is not problem with that. Can you please share some of the content of /u/bansalp/activemq_primary_plugin.stats.log.0?

Comment: I have added some log lines in question. There are other logs also in the file. This particular log lines are logged every half hour and other log lines are logged every minute.

Comment: Please note for few lines it parse quickly but when I tried parsing my whole log file it got stuck.

Comment: I changed my pattern in multiline codec and at least it starts to print something on screen with full data also.

Comment: so far what I have , it finds first matching line and then just stop there. I don't get any other output after first match.

Comment: If you are just using a file for testing and you will not be doing so in prod, then my suggestion is to switch to tcp input and use netcat to test input so that you can see the results in real time as you would during normal operation.